# Introduce a <br> for devices under 768pixels width

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

I have the following long subtitle:

**Selbsterfahrung | Persönlichkeitsentwicklung | Gesundheitsprävention**

whose HTML looks like this:

```
<h2>Selbsterfahrung <span class="divider"> | </span> Persönlichkeitsentwicklung <span class="divider"> | </span> Gesundheitsprävention</h2>
```

For devices under 768px width, I hide the "|" with a simple

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    .header-description .divider {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

But for devices under 1024 pixels I get the first two words in a first line and the last one in the second line, like this:

**Selbsterfahrung Persönlichkeitsentwicklung

Gesundheitsprävention**

which is not very nice

QUESTION:

**Is it possible to introduce a `<br>` for media under 1024pixels in the place of the SPAN tag?**

OR

**Is there any way to tell HTML to separate in a new line each word in devicesd under 768pixels width?**

So I would like to have each word in one separate line like:

**Selbsterfahrung
Persönlichkeitsentwicklung

Gesundheitsprävention**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `display: none`, you can put them into *separate lines* using `display: block` and make the dividers *invisible* using `visibility: hidden`.

Also throw in `font-size: 0` to the `divider` to remove the *space* it occupies.

See demo below:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  .divider {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Selbsterfahrung <span class="divider"> | </span> Persönlichkeitsentwicklung <span class="divider"> | </span> Gesundheitsprävention</h2>
```

Comment: This is a better approach than my answer, I should've thought of `visibility`

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 spans instead of one:

```
<h2>Selbsterfahrung <span class="divider-wide"> | </span><span class="divider-narrow"><br></span> Persönlichkeitsentwicklung <span class="divider-wide"> | </span><span class="divider-narrow"><br></span> Gesundheitsprävention</h2>
```

Then your css would be like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px) {
    .header-description .divider-wide {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 770px) {
    .header-description .divider-narrow {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Maybe there is something more elegant, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make the width of the parent smaller then the smallest word, like this:

```
.small-width {
    word-spacing: 10px; 
}
```

This way it will force to wrap the words in new lines